# Redis ZRANGEBYSCORE: what is offset and count

Tags: redis

```
ZRANGEBYSCORE key min max [WITHSCORES] [LIMIT offset count]
```

What is offset and count? How am I supposed to use them if I just want the member with the highest score?

Answer (score 2):

It is written here http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore.

Count and offset are used for pagination:

- Count is the number of results you want to display
- Offset is the number of results you already displayed